# Inspiron 15R 5537 - HDD in Optical bay caddy and SSD in Primary Bay - Not working But Other way round its working

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, dell-inspiron

Recently I planned to install SSD as primary storage for Windows 10 and current HDD as secondary storage.
I successfully installed OS in SSD and formatted OS from HDD but I am facing weird problem.

Before jump to the problem. Let me tell you what I did so far.

1. I installed SSD in optical bay caddy and initialize my Crucial BX500 240GB SSD.
2. Then I kept SSD in SATA bay by replacing HDD and then installed Windows 10, without putting HDD in optical caddy.
3. I tested OS startup and shutdown. It was lighting fast.
4. After installing OS in SSD when I installed Optical bay caddy with HDD in it. PC did not started and showing loading with Dell icon. After some time it showed "Scanning and repairing G:/ drive" of HDD.
5. So I switched position of SSD and HDD. SSD in Optical bay caddy and HDD in SATA/original bay. Laptop started without any problem.

But I am not sure whether SSD in Optical bay can give optimal performance or not.

Can you help me to solve this problem? **I want to keep SSD in SATA bay and HDD in Optical bay but it is not working.**

- Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15R 5537, i7 4th generation.
- Bios version: A12 (updated to latest)
- **Bios configuration: UEFI secure boot.  HDD and SSD both are GPT formatted.**
- SSD - Crucial BX500 240GB
- HDD - WD Blue 1 TB (included in Laptop)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Both devices are SATA I don’t see how their position would make a difference.  They are likely both SATA 3 connections since NVMe wouldn’t be applicable to the original mechanical drive nor the optical drive

Comment: What happened after Windows ran `ChkDsk` on `G:`? What exactly isn't working, as nothing in this question shows there's an issue running the HDD from the Optical Bay's SATA II connection?